# Why does 'this' not work as I expect in my Meteor event?

Tags: jquery, meteor, this

In my Meteor app, I've got this HTML:

```
<select class="trabajar d1s1j1" id="d1s1w1" name="d1s1w1" disabled>
  <option value="nothing">select someone</option>
  {{#each workers}}
    <option value={{w_emailaddr}}>{{w_firstname}} {{w_middlename}} {{w_lastname}} {{w_namesuffix}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

...and this jQuery:

```
Template.tblScheduler.events({
  'change #date1Shift1JobLoc1Count': function(event) {
    var enableCount = $('#date1Shift1JobLoc1Count').val();
    $('.d1s1j1').attr('disabled', 'disabled').slice(0, enableCount ).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

I first tried using:

```
var enableCount = $(this).val();
```

instead of:

```
var enableCount = $('#date1Shift1JobLoc1Count').val();
```

...but it doesn't work; however, "this" works just fine in a jsfiddle test case like so:

```
$('#abler').click(function () {
    var enableCount = 5;
    $('.d1s1j1').attr('disabled', 'disabled').slice(0, enableCount).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

So what gives - is this not this, or what this is this?

Comment: depends on the function as to what `this` is... you are comparing apples to oranges

Comment: It depends on how `Template.tblScheduler.events({` works. will have to wait for someone familiar with meteor i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Meteor, the `this` variable in an event handler refers to the data context where the element occurs. In your case the element is in a `{{#each}}` handlebars helper, so the `this` variable would refer to a single element of the `workers` array.

If you want to access the element where the event occurs using jQuery, you can just use:

```
$(event.currentTarget).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your event should look like this, if you want to get current target data.

```
Template.tblScheduler.events({
  'change #date1Shift1JobLoc1Count': function(event) {
     var enableCount = $(event.currentTarget).val();
   }
});
```